# Custom post type with two templates

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, templates, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I have a custom post type with an `archive-my-post-type` page and now I need a second archive page without header and footer and with a custom content.

So my question how can I create a second page with custom template which queries the posts from my custom post type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming post type is `my-post-type`.

We can create a page template with custom query using [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

Let's say we create `template-multier.php` with the below code in the root directory of the active theme.

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Custom Post Type Archive
   */

    //Custom header stuff here

    //Custom query for `my-post-type`

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1' // All posts
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Sample Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

    //Custom footer stuff here
```

Then we can use above page template to display posts with `my-post-type`

Comment: Thanks I know how I can create the template but my problem is how can I link to this template? I have a init funtion in my functions.php to init my custom post type and so I've created a archive-my-post-type.php which is called automatically... But I don't know how to call another template.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by **linking this template** ?

Comment: In my init function in the functions.php I have defined a slug e.g. "mitglieder" with this I can call my custom template mysite.com/mitglieder and now a I need a second page with the same posts but another template, do I need to create a second init function with another slug?

Comment: No. Create a page with what-ever name you need , let's say `mitglieder-two` and use the code above for the new template i have mentioned and then set `mitglieder-two` page template as the above